# Unable to set prefrence for restclient in firefoxprofile

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tired add the restclient extension in the selenium webdriver test. But the extensions is not getting added in the run time instance firefox. Can some one please help me how to add addon in browsers?

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

    // add any custom firefox configurations...
    profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "some UA string");
    profile.setPreference("javascript.options.showInConsole", true);
    profile.setPreference("dom.max_script_run_time", 0);

    // might have to uninstall, search for *.xpi, then reinstall, then search 
    // again and compare to find the location on your system
    // ...you should probably copy this into your selenium resources directory!
    File modifyHeadersXpi = new File("/home/nvenkat/.mozilla/firefox/djmkcg3c.default/extensions/{ad0d925d-88f8-47f1-85ea-8463569e756e}.xpi");
    if (modifyHeadersXpi.exists()) {
        profile.addExtension(modifyHeadersXpi);             
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.active", true);
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.openNewTab", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.sce.bypass_domain_mismatch", true);
        profile.setPreference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", false);
        profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.migrated", true);
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.autocomplete.name.defaults", 
                "[\"Accept\",\"Cache-Control\",\"Cookie\",\"Content-Length\",\"Content-Type\",\"Date\",\"Host\",\"Pragma\",\"Referer\",\"User-Agent\",\"Via\",\"X-Requested-With\",\"X-Forwarded-For\",\"X-Do-Not-Track\"]");
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 1);
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.action0", "Add");
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "sox");
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", "305471");
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", true);
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.active", true);
        profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn", true);

    }
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

what version of modify headers are you using?
the xpi in your profile is probably different than the one you used to install the extension.
here is how it works:

```
    FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
    try {
        fp.addExtension(new File("/foo/bar/modify_headers-0.7.1.1-fx.xpi"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle
    }
    fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 1);
    fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.action0", "Add");
    fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "X-Testing");
    fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", "your_value");
    fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", true);
    fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.active", true);
    fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn", true);

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Firefox profile first: Run Firefox -p, create new FFprofile.

`ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
            FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);`

Answer (score 0):

**Another way:**

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
    driver.get("https://addons.mozilla.org/en-S/firefox/addon/xxx/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("Add To FF button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(9000);

    Robot R = new Robot();
    R.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    R.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);

    R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT );
    R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    R.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    R.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);

    R.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    R.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);

    R.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT+KeyEvent.VK_R);
    R.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT+KeyEvent.VK_R);
    //R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT + KeyEvent.VK_R);
    R.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    ProfilesIni Newdriver = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile wdprofile = Newdriver.getProfile("default");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();




//enter code here`
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(wdprofile);`
    driver.get("chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html");`
```

`

```
    //FYI... webelement can't be identify by webdriver.Thats an open issue.
```